# Start a Workflow from within a Workflow, takes too long to start

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, workflow-designer

Using SharePoint Foundation
Got extensions from HarePoint

So I have a parent workflow that checks the categories of the item,
It can possibly activate 1 of 5 child workflows.

But whenever it starts a child workflow, the child workflow has a status of
"Starting" for max 5 mins. Sometimes it starts right away though.

Is there a way to remove the delay?